# Matlab isosurface plots lose 3d when used with subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a bunch of `isosurface` plots together with `subplot`, and I want them to appear 3d and be rotatable. However, I find that when I combine `subplot` with `isosurface` the plots appear 2d and are not rotatable. Here's a MRE:

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid([-3:0.25:3]); 
V = x.*exp(-x.^2 -y.^2 -z.^2);

for i=1:4
    subplot(2,2,i);

    isosurface(x,y,z,V,1e-4);
end
```

How can I make this rotatable? If I plot only one isosurface, without subplot, then it's in 3d and rotatable. If I use `subplot` with `surf`, I get 4 rotatable 3d surface plots. What am I missing here?

Comment: Here is a nice explanation of [why](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94581-why-do-i-get-a-different-result-from-isosurface-when-it-plots-to-a-subplot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94581-why-do-i-get-a-different-result-from-isosurface-when-it-plots-to-a-subplot), `subplot` first splits your figure into different areas and creates a 2d axis object in one of the areas.

When you then `isosurface` **after** the call to subplot, MATLAB does a 2d projection of `isosurface` onto the 2d axis.

`surf` works differently, because it forces the conversion of the axis object where it is plotted to a 3d axis object. These behaviors can be recreated as follows:

```
figure;
plot(1,1)
surf([1,2;1,2],[1,1;2,2],[1 1 ; 1 1]);
```

[image]

```
figure
plot(1,1)
isosurface(x,y,z,V,1e-4);
```

[image]

A workaround for this is to force the conversion to a 3d Axis object with `view(3)`(plus re-adding `camlight`):

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid([-3:0.25:3]); 
V = x.*exp(-x.^2 -y.^2 -z.^2);

figure;

for ii = 1:4

subplot(2,2,ii);
isosurface(x,y,z,V,1e-4);
view(3)
camlight;

end
```

[image]